# is there a difference between select value from string_split and select * from string_split

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm running the query below and the select statements yield the same results.  Is there a benefit to using 1 vs the other and will these always yield in the same result?

```
declare @session varchar(max)='347021,347020'
select * from string_split(@session,',')
select value from string_split(@session,',')
```

Edit/Solved

As [Zhorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6578080/zhorov) mentions in the comments, if i were to turn on the optional ordinal argument in string_split, this would result in more than 1 column, so the results are not the same.  Please note - The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: I think both the same from your sample, but if there are some cross apply or join tables you will get a lot different, I would always use select `column` clearly

Comment: From [dcos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) - _STRING_SPLIT outputs a single-column or double-column table, depending on the enable_ordinal argument_

Comment: `*` is simplied replaced, by SQL Server, with a list of *all* the columns from *all* the objects in the `FROM` at the time the code is compiled. If you list all the column or use `*` will likely not have any performance issues. That doesn't mean you should be using `*` though; it's always best to be explicit on the columns you want.

Comment: You should just always name the columns you want rather than rely on exceptions for the rare cases where there is no additional benefit. To save 4 characters of typing? Why? Be explicit.

Comment: If you use `select *` it is entirely possible that SQL Server might introduce additional columns to the default result set in the future that could block you moving the database to a later compatibility level some years from now - and this would be entirely avoidable by just using best practices now.

Comment: @Zhorov thank you...this answers my question.  There is an optional `enable ordinal` argument which would result in more than 1 column; however, `The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only).`

Comment: I might point out you can't use `*` in a schema-bound function, eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eed3b589d933d85e364234a2e2ae4c89